# Python (fastapi) - TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi

I have had a recurring error during practice with fastapi and the postgresql database, at the time of viewing the data that i have saved. When i want to see a data written in a single digit like "1" or "3", nothing wrong happens, but when a wrote a number with more digit like "10" or "12" it shows me the error TypeError : not all arguments converted during string formatting. HERE PART OF THE CODE

```
    class User(BaseModel):
        id: Optional[int]
        first_name: str
        last_name: str
        phone: str
        email: str
        department: str


@user.get("/users/{id}")
def get_user(id: int):
    connect_db()
    mycur=myconn.cursor()
    query= ''' SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id =%s'''
    mycur.execute(query, str(id))
    
    return mycur.fetchone()
```

i need help with that. i hope someone could help me here

Comment: The parameters passed to `cursor.execute` should be in a list/tuple/iterable, passing a string with two characters is interpreted as two parameters as the string is iterated over. Pass your parameters in a tuple or list: `mycur.execute(query, [str(id)])`

Comment: In addition to what @IainShelvington said, is  `id` actually a string(varchar/text) field? If not and it is an integer field you can skip the `str(id)` conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much @IainShelvington you were right about the parameters . Change my code and now work nicely

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [iain-shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington), you need to pass the parameters in a tuple or list. Only one addition, if you plan to use a tuple, you need to put a **comma** in the end.

- mycur.execute(query, [str(id)])  # Example of list
- mycur.execute(query, (str(id),)  # Example of tuple